# How to abstract same behavior of different classes

Tags: java

I'm a Java web beginner. Today I came onto the following scenario:

I have several classes with no inheritance relationship like `ClassA` and `ClassB`

```java
public class ClassA {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
}

public class ClassB {
    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private String b3;
}
```

Functions to process them are exactly the same, except for the input parameter type and some get methods.

```java
public void function functionA(ClassA a) {
    ...
    Object[] obj = new Object[]{a.getA2()};
    ...
    
}

public void function functionB(ClassB b) {
    ...
    Object[] obj = new Object[]{b.getB1(),b.getB2(),b.getB3()};
    ...
    
}
```

Apparently, writing in this way causes code duplication and low scalability, I've tried to make it tidy, but I have no idea about handling with the input type difference.

Could any one tell me how to extract the common logic of `functionA` and `functionB`?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Spring or Spring Boot. Seems like more of a general design question. Extract the common part to a method, call that with the needed input.

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstraction to extract common functionality - define an interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {

  Object[] getValues();
}
```

Have your classes implement it. Then refactor your handler method to accept `MyInterface`.

```
public void function(MyInterface myInterface) {
  Object[] values = myInterface.getValues();
  //handle
}
```

I would also suggest to read this question - [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) - it has one of the best explanations on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you are looking for something akin to interfaces. I'm gonna make some assumptions but it looks like you are trying to put all the fields of a class in an `Object[]` array and are looking for a way to do so without having many methods with different input parameters..

So what you could do is create an interface `IMyInterface` (sorry for the unoriginal name):

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    public Object[] toObjectArray();
}
```

Your `ClassA` and `ClassB` could then both implement this interface:

```
public class ClassA implements IMyInterface {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;

    @Override
    public Object[] toObjectArray() {
        return new Object[]{ getA1(), getA2() };
    }
}

public class ClassB implements IMyInterface {
    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private String b3;

    @Override
    public Object[] toObjectArray() {
        return new Object[]{ getB1(), getB2(), getB3() };
    }
}
```

This would make the `ClassA` and `ClassB` in control of how the object array is built up.

Then, in the rest of your application, you can simply use this `IMyInterface` instance to either accept parameters of type `ClassA` or `ClassB`:

```
public void someFunction(IMyInterface item) {
    Object[] obj = item.toObjectArray();
    // Rest of your code..
}
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.